# Why does my login form keeps saying wrong password/email

Tags: c#, xaml, authentication

I made a login form with XAML and here is the code for when the password is wrong

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(txtEmail.Text == "test@test.com" && txtPass.Text == "test")
        {
            mainWindow.mainFrame.Navigate(new Uri("/pages/dashboard.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
            MessageBox.Show("Successfully Logged in");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Email/Password is incorrect, try again.");
            txtPass.Text = " ";
            txtEmail.Text = " ";
            txtEmail.Focus();
        }
    }
```

Idk where i got it wrong because im new to this but it keeps on showing the messagebox saying the pass/email is wrong eventhough ive typed it correctly.

Comment: Your code looks fine. Try stepping through your code and verify the input on your 2 text boxes using a breakpoint.

Comment: If your code compiles, it must be a binding issue. That means the value of txtEmail.Text is probably null, and whatever you type in your textbox never reaches the code behind. Please send your XAML markup as well so we may get the full picture.

Comment: By XAML markup do you mean the XAML code? (sorry im new to this lol)